# The socket.on not working correctly in the flutter

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I create a class to manage socket and use it in the `main.dart` class.

```
class SocketServices {
  static late Socket socket;

  static void connect() async {
    socket = io(
        'http://server-address',
        OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket'])
            .disableAutoConnect()
            .build());
    socket.connect();
  }

  static void disConnect() {
    socket.disconnect()
      ..dispose()
      ..close();
  }
}
```

It connects correctly. When I use this socket in one of the pages to listen to an event, it doesn't connect:

```
@override
void onInit() {
  super.onInit();
  SocketServices.socket.on("online_players",(data) {
    print(data.toString());
  });
}
```

But, when I use `socket.on` in the connecting method of `SocketServices` class, it returns data correctly.

```
static void connect() async {
  socket = io(
      'http://45.147.160.146:5000',
      OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .disableAutoConnect()
          .build());
  socket.connect();
  socket.on("online_users", (data){
    print(data);
  });
}
```

What difference? I need that data on one of the pages, How can I declare `socket.on` in `SocketServices` class and use live data on that page?

Comment: seems like you are listening to the socket without connecting first.

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa no no I'm sure to connect to the socket first.